# Cannot filter the data in Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, filter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to filter data in Firestore and when I print the info to the console I get all documents. The Firestore database is structured as follows:

```
/Collection
   /auto-doc ID
        / hosp : "hosp1"
          team : "team1"
          (there are more fields in every document)
```

For testing purposes I only have six documents and two of them have the field I want to filter and print to the console (hosp1).

```
@IBAction func getData2(_ sender: Any) {

    if HOSP != "hosp1" {
        query = Firestore.firestore().collection(PTLIST_REF).whereField("hosp", isEqualTo: "hosp1")
        ptListCollectionRef.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                debugPrint("error getting data: \(err)")
            }
            else {
                for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                    print(document.data())
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting all the documents because you are calling `getDocuments()` functions on a collection reference and not on a query. With other words, you aren't applying any filters at all. To be able to filter your data, please change the following line of code:

```
ptListCollectionRef.getDocuments {/* ... */}
```

to

```
query.getDocuments {/* ... */}
```

Comment: that did it.Thank you sir!!